# On load function checking for button controle

Tags: javascript

I inherited VScript code that will create a web service redirect button based on logged in user; if the user is not found the button is not created and error text is displayed, I was asked to set up onload javascript function to automatically click the button-that i did.I need to check if the button exists first before i click it.What is the best way to do check if the button exist onload in javascript?

Thnaks

Comment: You can check an element exists by its ID using `document.getElementById` if you know it, but you really should provide a code listing with minimal reproduction of what you are asking.

Comment: Yes @Tom..I have created below with sample code finding it using document.getElementById with body on load ..but it got down voted :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
var button = document.getElementById("the button's id");

window.onload = function() {
    if (button != null) {
        // your code
    }
}
```